# Advantages of returning by reference?

Tags: c++

I came across the code, where in a class one of the member function returns by reference. What are the advantages of doing it like that? E.g.:

```
class SomeClass {
    std:vector<int> some_vals;
    // some functions that modify some_vals
public:
    const std::vector<int>& get_some_vals() const { return some_vals; }
};
```

And then when the function is used:

```
SomeClass my_obj;
const vector<int>& some_vals = my_obj.get_some_vals();
```

What is the advantage of doing it like this instead of just returning std::vector?

Comment: Try to work out, on piece of paper, what happens when this vector has a million values.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but if I had to guess, I assume you are referring to copying the vector twice and constructing all the values each time in case of return by value? Or is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Nope, that's pretty much it. You've pretty much answered your own question.

Comment: But I thought the return value optimization would take care of this by moving the vector instead of copying in case the return is const. Is it not the case?

Comment: @user_185051 Wouldn't moving make the vector member unusable? I doubt that RVO can apply there. That's applicable for function locally defined variables only.

Comment: "Moving" the vector means the original vector, the class member, gets destroyed. That's what "moving" means. "Moving" doesn't mean "make a copy of the original object, which remains unmodified". That's not how move semantics work.